# El significado de "por cuenta del que actúa"

Tags: significado-en-contexto, lenguaje-jurídico

Según RAE en el *Diccionario panhispánico del español jurídico*, [cónsul honorario](https://dpej.rae.es/lema/c%C3%B3nsul-honorario) es:

> Persona que no suele tener la nacionalidad del país **por cuenta del que actúa**, sino la del de residencia o la de un tercer Estado, que no es funcionario de carrera y que solo es competente para ejercer un número limitado y secundario de las funciones consulares.

Quisiera saber el significado de "por cuenta del que actúa" en "persona que no suele tener la nacionalidad del pais por cuenta del que actua" y a qué país se refiere.

(Por cierto, parece que hay un errata en "sino la del de residencia", o sea, debería ser "sino la de residencia", ¿no es así?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según el DLE, un [*cónsul*](https://dle.rae.es/c%C3%B3nsul) es:

> Persona autorizada en una población de un Estado extranjero para proteger las personas e intereses de los individuos de la nación que la nombra.

Generalmente, la persona es del país que representa. Es decir, si eres un cónsul de Alemania, sueles ser alemán y te envían a Francia a ejercer de *cónsul alemán en Francia*.

El de *cónsul honorario* es un título que, como indica su nombre, es honorario y se otorga generalmente por méritos generalmente. De ahí que sea una especie de *agradecimiento* de un país a un miembro del otro.

Dado todo este contexto, cuando dice *Persona que no suele tener la nacionalidad del país por cuenta del que actúa, sino la del de residencia o la de un tercer Estado* se refiere a que el cónsul honorario suele ser una persona que representa a un país del que no es original.
Siguiendo con el ejemplo de antes, podríamos hablar de *El francés Michael Perigord fue designado cónsul honorario de Alemania en Francia por su larga colaboración en la importación de productos alemanes en Francia*.

---

> (Por cierto, parece que hay un errata en "sino la del de residencia", o sea, debería ser "sino la de residencia", ¿no es así?)

La frase dice:

> Persona que no suele tener la nacionalidad del país por cuenta del que actúa, **sino la del de residencia** o la de un tercer Estado (...)

Este *sino la del de residencia* se refiere a la nacionalidad. Por tanto, está diciendo *persona que suele tener la nacionalidad del país de residencia*. Esto es, que el cónsul honorario suele ser nacional del país en el que vive y no del que lo designa. El *del* en *del de residencia* es necesario pues remite al sintagma *del país* de la frase inicial.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones! Tengo otra duda sobre el "del" que aparece dos veces en la definición de "cónsul honorario":  ¿Se refieren a un mismo país el "del" en "por cuenta del que actúa" y el "del" en "sino la del de residencia" ? Muchas gracias otra vez 

Comment: @Maurice cuando dice _Persona que no suele tener la nacionalidad DEL1 país por cuenta DEL2 que actúa, sino la DEL3 de residencia_, tanto DEL1 como DEL2 se refieren al "país", mientras que DEL3 se refiere al de residencia.

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad, fedorqui .